# Dell X4012 copper options?

Tags: switch, dell, 10gbethernet, sfp

I've been using the Dell X4012 12x 10GbE switches with fibre and DAC cabling in several of our locations for a year now, and their lack of SFP+ ID checking made them easy to integrate. However, now I need to get some of these switches into an environment where I just can't use fibre or DACs due to lack of SFP+ slots on the existing switches. Dell does not list any 10Gb Copper SFP+ modules in their compatibility lists, and a support ticket confirmed that "they are not officially supported in this switch".

**Which brings me to my question: just not officially supported, or not working at all?**

Since the X4012 do not care at all about manufacturer IDs on the SFP+ (I've plugged Cisco, Finisar, noname, HP modules in there, whatever I had at hand, they all worked), and it does not seem to have any real way to distinguish between fibre and copper links (at least all the 1Gb copper SFPs all show up as fibre in the web management GUI) or even the speed capabilities (I had to set the 1Gb copper SPFs manually to 1Gb because the switch tried to negotiate at 10Gb).. it might just not care at all and talk through 10Gb copper SFP+ just fine.

Has anyone tried that yet, and can probably share model/vendor of the SFP+ modules with me, or prevent me from burning money on a futile attempt?